# Katalon automatic tests don't validate Basic Authorization of API

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I need some help with Basic Authorization of API - I testing with Katalon Studio, but if you have any suggestion with Selenium solutions I will be grateful too.

Simplest way doesn't work in my API - I mean: WebUI.openBrowser("http://username:password@example.com") - It's validating but in wrong way - It redirecting me to main page, but I have error "too many network errors".

When I putting data manually, it's redirecting me in right site.

I working on Mac and method with [WebUI] Authenticate it's not for me, because it's only for Windows(?!).

Maybe I can use POST request,  but I'm beginner I really don't know how I can use it to pass basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://username:password@example.com', FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
```

Comment: Of course, It was my first try :) And I get error from website

Comment: Also let us know *what* you have tried so far (by updating your question).